# Why is my code printing all names in the list instead of just player 1: name?

Tags: python

```
# TODO Create an empty list to maintain the player names
players = []

# TODO Ask the user if they'd like to add players to the list.
# If the user answers "Yes", let them type in a name and add it to the list.
# If the user answers "No", print out the team 'roster'
add_players = input("Would you like to add a player to the list? (Yes/No) ")
while add_players.lower() == "yes":
  name = input("\nEnter the name of the player to add to the team: ")
  players.append(name)
  add_players = input("Would you like to add another player? (Yes/No)")


# TODO print the number of players on the team
print("\nThere are {} players on the team.".format(len(players)))

# TODO Print the player number and the player name
# The player number should start at the number one
player_number = 1
for player in players:
  print("Player {}: {}".format(player_number, players))
  player_number += 1

# TODO Select a goalkeeper from the above roster
keeper = input("Please select the goal keeper by selecting the 
player_number. (1-{})".format(len(players)))

# TODO Print the goal keeper's name
# Remember that lists use a zero based index
print("Great!! The goalkeeper for the game will be 
{}".format(players[keeper-1]))
```

I want the list to display a rooster like
player 1: charlie
player 2: john
player 3: tommy
but the current code is showing me this output:
[image: 1]

Comment: You're printing `players`. You probably want to print `player`.

Comment: player is not defined

Comment: Meaning what exactly…?

Comment: You should write `print("Player {}: {}".format(player_number, player))`

Comment: players is defined as it is a list which contains name of all players but player is not defined anywhere in the code. Please check the image of the output.

Comment: Actually, you have defined `player` in the `for` loop. I tried to change `players` into `player`. It works for me. Also, I added `int` in the input `keeper = int(input("Please select the goal keeper by selecting the player_number. (1-{})".format(len(players))))`

Comment: It worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should replace `players` with `player`:

```
for i, player in enumerate(players):
    print("Player {}: {}".format(i+1, player))
```

Comment: Or `enumerate(players, 1)`…